# Mongoose .find() with conditions returns no result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean

I am working on a MEAN Stack app with a pre-existing MongoDB collection and if I define conditions for .find() no results were returned while it works without conditions.

Here is the code from my model file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var mainSchema = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    x: Number,
    y: Number,
    prio: Number,
    type0: String,
    type1: String,
    type2: String,
    width: Number,
    height: Number,
    text1: String,
    text2: String,
    size1: Number,
    font: String,
    color1: String,
    color2: String,
    links: String,
    peers: String
}, { collection: 'main' });

mainSchema.statics = {
    load: function(l, t, r, b, cb){
        console.log(l, t, r, b);
        return this.find({
            x: { $gt: l, $lt: r },
            y: { $gt: t, $lt: b } 
        }).exec(cb);
    }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('main', mainSchema);
```

This is one object from the output without conditions:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "577faf952a7c33f2fe44b282",
    "id": 4,
    "x": 50944,
    "y": 54995,
    "prio": 1,
    "type0": "a",
    "type1": "a",
    "type2": "a",
    "width": 100,
    "height": 100,
    "text1": "Chemie",
    "text2": "",
    "size1": 48,
    "font": "f1_a ",
    "color1": "#000000",
    "color2": "#bfdeff",
    "links": "14,53445,57328,12,#ff3d3d,k&13,54744,53904,12,#8c8c86,k&12,52557,51870,12,#f2ff12,k&11,51172,49743,12,#2312ff,k&10,48270,47335,12,#49fe6e,k&",
    "peers": "1"
  }
]
```

Here is the code that calls the load methode:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var main = require('../models/main');

exports.load = function(req, res){
    main.load(parseInt(req.query.l), parseInt(req.query.t), parseInt(req.query.r), parseInt(req.query.b), function(err, data) {
        res.jsonp(data);
    });
};
```

Comment: Where is the code that calls the load method?

Comment: @chridam Thanks for the hint, I added the code.

Comment: I believe you are calling the wrong model instance here; instead of `var Main = mongoose.model('main', "main", 'main');`, why can't you call the actual model as `var Main = require('../models/main');` and make sure you export it in the main.js file at the end as `module.exports = mongoose.model('main', mainSchema);`?

Comment: Or use `var Main = mongoose.model('main')` (single argument with the model name).

Comment: I used chridams advice but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
Despite the output all data were stored as strings instead of int within MongoDB. 
I just copied the JSON output (where the types are correct) to a file and imported it to MongoDB, now the code works fine.